# Transform PointCloud message

Tags: c++, pcl, pointcloud, tf2, ros-foxy

I am receiving a `sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud` (base_link frame) in my callback. I want to transform this PointCloud to the camera frame, so that I can do a projection of that point cloud view.

I am having problems to convert a `sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud` into a `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;` with ROS 2 Foxy. How can I do it?

My CPP code:

```
void my_callback(const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud::SharedPtr msg)
{
    // cloud_in should be the PointCloud message
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud_in;
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud_out;

    geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped transform;

    try
    {
        transform = tfBuffer_->lookupTransform("camera_frame", msg->header.frame_id, tf2::TimePointZero);
        pcl_ros::transformPointCloud(cloud_in, cloud_out, transform);
    }
    catch (tf2::TransformException &ex)
    {
        RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Transform error: %s", ex.what());
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem in this function? Can you provide the logs of the execution of this node?

Comment: as it is it won't do nothing, because my PointCloud msg isn't converted in a pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> as desired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

I have noticed several concerns with your code snippet, which I would like to address below:

1. Change the signature of your callback to receive `sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2` instead of `sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud`. Below is an example:

   ```
   void my_callback(const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr msg)
   ```
2. Use `pcl::PCLPointCloud2` instead of `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>`.
3. Use `pcl_conversions::toPCL` to convert `sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2` to `pcl::PCLPointCloud2` as shown below:

   ```
   pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PCLPointCloud2());
   // Convert ROS2 Pointcloud2 to PCL Pointcloud2
   //   Don't foerget to add followings:
   //     #include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
   //     find_package(pcl_conversions REQUIRED)
   pcl_conversions::toPCL(*msg,*cloud);
   ```
4. Finally, you should be able to use `pcl_ros::transformPointCloud` to transform your point cloud from `base_link` to `camera_link`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ravi! I am subscribing a topic that publishes a ```sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud```. I get following output after running ```ros2 topic list -t```: ```/my/point_cloud [sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud]```. Shouldn't I use then ```sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud```?

Comment: @renan:  I am worried seeing old style `sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud` in your package. First please subscribe to `sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2`. If it does not work, please see [here](https://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview#Point_Cloud_conversion). On a side note, ROS 2 Foxy is [EOL](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Releases.html).  and will no longer receive support

Comment: With ```convertPointCloudToPointCloud2``` I can now convert my PC to PC2. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a good first step is to convert to PointCloud2 using the snippet from [`convertPointCloudtoPointCloud2`](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/master/sensor_msgs/include/sensor_msgs/point_cloud_conversion.hpp) from the package `sensor_msgs`.

then you can use `pcl_conversions::moveToPCL` or `pcl_conversions::toPCL`

Comment: Thank you for your input. As @ravi gave me the same answer and some other suggestions, I accepted his, but I appreciate your efforts. Cheers!